# How to automate release notes / changelog creation?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, redmine, nexus

How to automate build notes / changelog creation ?

That is in the end of sprint generate list of closed issues, link it to released artifacts, put into maven generated site, publish on Redmine wiki...

We use Jenkins, Maven, Nexus, Redmine, (...other tools?) (see tags below)

I need ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's the [maven changes plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/) and what is (hopefully, never tried) an [equivalent for redmine](http://maven-site.nuiton.org/jredmine/maven-jredmine-plugin/). both of these plugins do the same thing basically - they query your issue management/bug tracker for issues between releases and write them down. from there you have various ways of formatting this into html (xslt for one).

put this under some maven profile that only jenkins runs so builds wont slow down for developers.

Answer (score 3):

There is also this redmine plugin https://github.com/hdgarrood/redmine_release_notes .

You need automation on which side: jenkins or redmine?

Comment: Any tools that help to save time and increase productivity/team velocity.